# how to increase upload size with dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core

I use dotnet core and i got error like this :

```
HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.
```

I've tried use this :

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

I also tried :

```
[HttpPost]
        [RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
        public IActionResult ProcessFile(IFormFile file)
        {
```

but still cant upload file with size 50MB +

how to increase upload size in dotnet core 2

I use IIS Express

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155342/default-limits-limits-for-iis-express/28437720#28437720

Comment: yes I've tried it before

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112438/1204153